# Split object keys with same prefix to new objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

For example, given an object with keys and values

```
{
  prefix_1_a: 1a,
  prefix_1_b: 1b,
  prefix_2_a: 2a,
  prefix_2_b: 2b,
}
```

I want convert into two objects:

1. `prefix_1` with keys and values `{a: 1a, b: 1b}`
2. `prefix_2` with keys and values `{a: 2a, b: 2b}`

another example ,given a formData object:

```
["item_0_orange":"10",
"item_0_apple:"20",
"item_0_grape":"30",
"item_1_orange":"40",
"item_1_apple":"50",
"item_1_grape":"60",
"item_2_orange":"40",
"item_2_apple":"50",
"item_2_grape":"60"]
```

and I want to convert to json object

```
fruitprice:
[
{key:0 ,orange:"10" , apple:"20" , grape:"30" },
{key:1 ,orange:"40" , apple:"50" , grape:"60" },
{key:2 ,orange:"40" , apple:"50" , grape:"60" }
]
```

1. how to search and add key and value under  a position when match same prefix

here is my code:

```
var fruitObject ={};
for(i=0;i<3;i++) 
      {
          var prefix = "item_" + i;
          var res = key.split("_");
          var newKey = res[2];

          if(key.startsWith(prefix))
          {
             var newObject = {};
             newObject[newKey] =value;
             addObject(res[1],newObject, fruitObject); //by given key  
             return;
          };
      }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Object.entries and String.prototype.split are your friends.

Comment: let me explain more , i got a form of repeating items (20) . for example , item 1 with  price 1 . item 2 with price 2  . I use formData to covert it to a object . the object became  item_1 ="" ,item_price1 ="" , item_2="" , item_price2="" ...... as finally i want to covert in to json , i have to sprit it in to a list of object instead of named item1 .....item2

Comment: add you object here in code block

Answer (score 0):

It can be a costly transformation, but not that complex:

Let's start with the input:

```
const data = {
  "item_0_orange": "10",
  "item_0_apple": "20",
  "item_0_grape": "30",
  "item_1_orange": "40",
  "item_1_apple": "50",
  "item_1_grape": "60",
  "item_2_orange": "40",
  "item_2_apple": "50",
  "item_2_grape": "60",
}
```

Then have a look at the desired output:

```
const fruitprices = [
  {
    key: 0,
    orange: "10",
    apple: "20",
    grape: "30"
  },
  {
    key: 1,
    orange: "40",
    apple: "50",
    grape: "60",
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    orange: "40",
    apple: "50",
    grape: "60",
  }
]
```

And here's a transformation from `data` to `fruitprices`:

```js
// this is an Object, not an Array!
const data = {
  "item_0_orange": "10",
  "item_0_apple": "20",
  "item_0_grape": "30",
  "item_1_orange": "40",
  "item_1_apple": "50",
  "item_1_grape": "60",
  "item_2_orange": "40",
  "item_2_apple": "50",
  "item_2_grape": "60",
}

// transform function
const fruitprices = Object.entries(data).reduce((a, [key, val]) => {
  // destructuring the key; "prefix" is not going to be used
  const [prefix, outkey, fruit] = key.split('_')

  // trying to find the item in the "a" Array
  const item = a.find(({
    key: itemkey
  }) => itemkey === outkey)

  if (item) { // if the key is already in the "a" Array
    item[fruit] = val
  } else { // if the key is not in the "a" Array yet
    a.push({
      key: outkey,
      [fruit]: val
    })
  }

  return a
}, [])

console.log(fruitprices)
```

Comment: can i ask about this code  ```const item = a.find(({
    key: itemkey
  }) => itemkey === outkey)```? not quite understand ```key:itemkey``` ,

Comment: or should i just get form data with class name item_0 , item_1 , item_2 , then i just specify group of input apple , orange , grape with class name ...seeking for a better solution when posting same group input with JSON format

Comment: @annann don’t worry about “key: itemkey” - that’s just destructuring & renaming the variable in the scope of the “find”, because “key” variable name has been already used in the “reduce” scope. :)

Comment: @annann as for getting the form data in other ways: sorry, with the information given, I cannot help you with the data structure. I don’t know what options you have, what is the final goal. Without that one structure is as good as any other.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping . I googled and this is a ideal solution for me  https://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/ , but it doesn't support current , any suggestion if i want to covert form structure to JSON , ```<form enctype='application/json'>
  <input name='pet[species]' value='Dahut'>
  <input name='pet[name]' value='Hypatia'>
  <input name='kids[1]' value='Thelma'>
  <input name='kids[0]' value='Ashley'>
</form>

// produces
{
    "pet":  {
        "species":  "Dahut"
    ,   "name":     "Hypatia"
    }
,   "kids":   ["Ashley", "Thelma"]
}```